# QSS memory leaks

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qtstylesheets

There are memory leaks when I setting qss to QWidget. Code:

```
QString checkBoxSelectionQSS = "QCheckBox, QCheckBox::indicator{ background-color: transparent; border: none; } QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked { image: url(:/resource/selectionIconUnchecked.png); } QCheckBox::indicator:checked { image: url(:/resource/selectionIconChecked.png); } QCheckBox::indicator { subcontrol-position: center center; }";
QString checkBoxVisibleQSS = "QCheckBox, QCheckBox::indicator{ background-color: transparent; border: none; } QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked { image: url(:/resource/visibleIconUnchecked.png); } QCheckBox::indicator:checked { image: url(:/resource/visibleIconChecked.png); } QCheckBox::indicator { subcontrol-position: center center; }";
QString pushButtonRemoveQSS = "QPushButton{ background-color: transparent; border: none; image: url(:/resource/removeIcon.png); }";

QCheckBox* pCheckBox = new QCheckBox;
pCheckBox->setChecked(true);
pCheckBox->setStyleSheet(checkBoxVisibleQSS);
pTree->setItemWidget(pItem, 1, pCheckBox);

connect(pCheckBox, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(SetVisibleItem(bool)));

pCheckBox = new QCheckBox;
pCheckBox->setChecked(true);
pCheckBox->setStyleSheet(checkBoxSelectionQSS);
pTree->setItemWidget(pItem, 2, pCheckBox);

connect(pCheckBox, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(SetSelectabelItem(bool)));

QPushButton* pPushButton = new QPushButton;
pPushButton->setStyleSheet(pushButtonRemoveQSS);
pTree->setItemWidget(pItem, 3, pPushButton);

connect(pPushButton, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(RemoveItem()));
```

All the images specified in qss have a size from 7 to 50 KB, but the memory for each widget is about 2MB. If comment on the *setStyleSheet()*, then no leakage occurs.

Comment: What is `pTree`? If it is a `QTreeWidget`, [`QTreeWidget::setItemWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#setItemWidget) takes ownership of the widget passed in (`pCheckBox`), so what @NathanOliver said wouldn't apply here

Comment: @Justin pTree is a QTreeWidget class.

Comment: Two things: 1) 7KB  to 50 KB in PNG format will be way more once the picture is loaded and decompressed. 2) How are you measuring the memory usage? valgrind?